# How should I pause an SVG animation to remain with a static image after all previous animations have played?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, themes

I have never worked with SVG's before. I have one here I'd like to pause its transition and maintain a static image after all the previous animations have successfully loaded, I have tried most CSS animation rules but none has worked well.

The class used in the animation div is "theme-main-banner" as far as I'm concerned. How to pause the slider animation?

**Tried to pause it here at the theme-slider function.**

```js
"use strict";


// Theme-banner slider
function BannerSlider() {
  var banner = $("#theme-main-banner");
  if (banner.length) {
    banner.camera({
      //here I declared some settings, the height and the presence of the thumbnails
      height: "47%",
      pagination: false,
      navigation: true,
      thumbnails: false,
      playPause: false,
      pauseOnClick: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      hover: false,
      overlayer: true,
      loader: "none",
      minHeight: "700px",
      time: 4000
    });
  }
}

// Inner Banner
function innerBanner() {
  if ($(".inner-page-banner").length) {
    $(".inner-page-banner").ripples({
      resolution: 312,
      dropRadius: 10,
      perturbance: 0.001
    });
  }
}

// WOW animation
function wowAnimation() {
  if ($(".wow").length) {
    var wow = new WOW({
      boxClass: "wow", // animated element css class (default is wow)
      animateClass: "animated", // animation css class (default is animated)
      mobile: true, // trigger animations on mobile devices (default is true)
      live: true, // act on asynchronously loaded content (default is true)
      callback: function(box) {
        // the callback is fired every time an animation is started
        // the argument that is passed in is the DOM node being animated
      },
      scrollContainer: null // optional scroll container selector, otherwise use window
    });
    wow.init();
  }
}

// Portfolio Silder
function portfolioSlider() {
  var cSlider = $(".portfolio-slider");
  if (cSlider.length) {
    cSlider.owlCarousel({
      animateOut: "slideOutLeft",
      loop: true,
      nav: false,
      dots: false,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 4000,
      smartSpeed: 1200,
      lazyLoad: true,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1
        },
        551: {
          items: 2
        },
        768: {
          items: 3
        },
        992: {
          items: 4
        }
      }
    });
  }
}



// DOM ready function
jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {
  (function($) {
    removePlaceholder();
    BannerSlider();
    wowAnimation();
    mixitupGallery();
    testimonialSlider();
    portfolioSlider();
    partnersLogo();
    CounterNumberChanger();
    scrollToTop();
    contactFormValidation();
    closeSuccessAlert();
    themeAccrodion();
    priceRanger();
    productValue();
    productSlider();
  })(jQuery);
});
```

```css
 }
  #theme-main-banner .camera_prev,
  #theme-main-banner .camera_next {
    display: none;
  }
  .banner-two h1,
  .banner-three .container h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
  }
  .banner-two .play-option,
  .banner-three .play-option {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  
  
#theme-main-banner .camera_prev:before {content: '';}
#theme-main-banner .camera_next:before {content: '';}

#theme-main-banner .camera_prev>span, #theme-main-banner .camera_next>span {display: none;}
#theme-main-banner .camera_overlayer {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#theme-main-banner.banner-one .camera_overlayer {
  background: url(../images/home/shape-1.png) no-repeat center center;
}
#theme-main-banner.camera_wrap .camera_pag .camera_pag_ul {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top:50%;
  left:38px;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#theme-main-banner .camera_caption {
  height: 100%;
}
#theme-main-banner .container {position: relative;}
#theme-main-banner .camera_caption>div {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-shadow: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-main-banner" class="banner-one">
    <div data-src="images/home/slide-1.jpg">
        <div class="camera_caption">
            <div class="container">
                <h5 class="wow fadeInUp animated">Strategic Campaigns</h5>
                <h2 class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <span>We efficiently develop</span>
                    <br>
                    <span>guerilla marketing</span>
                    <br>
                    <span>campaigns for your project.</span>
                </h2>

                <div class="wow fadeInRight animated image-shape-one">
                    <svg version="1.1" class="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="778"
                     height="576">
                        <clipPath class="clip1">
                            <use xlink:href="#shape-one" />
                        </clipPath>
                        <g clip-path="url(#shape-one)">
                            <image width="778" height="576" href="images/home/home.png" class="banner-img-one">
                            </image>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <!--div class="wow fadeInRight animated image-shape-two" data-wow-delay="0.39s"><div class="theme-shape-two"></div></div-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.camera_caption -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my [project](https://preview.c9users.io/toshmania/svg) files.

Answer (score 0):

### Try the transition delay property

I had to put a delay on a transition in a case where I wanted the transition to fire off at separate times.

```
div {
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```